# Load Balancing webservers using Httpurlconnection on client side

Tags: java, load-balancing

My application needs to connect to a web service to get xml data. I have four web service endpoints.

What is the best way to load balance between web service?

I know best way is to use Hardware/software Load Balancer but i have to do on client side.

i have develop a client using HttpURLConnection which is working fine for any one end point.

I am planning to use hashmap for URL's and after that call one by one.

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a central point to co-ordinate distribution of connections between your service endpoints, you're pretty much limited to choosing an arbitrary one-of-four each time you establish a connection. A reasonable approach may be to use each endpoint in turn for successive interactions from the client (starting with one chosen at random to ensure that there isn't heavy bias towards a single endpoint at times when the clients may be restarted).

Alternatively, you could implement an endpoint that returns a preferred connection, from which the client will make subsequent calls. The implementation could then assign clients round robin style, or with reference to the load reported by each endpoint at any given time.

Of the two approaches, the former is by far the simpler and should give reasonably even distribution across the endpoints. The latter would allow additional endpoints to be added without requiring that the clients be updated.

Comment: Potentially a more useful variation of the second approach would be for the client to retrieve a list of available endpoints, possibly ordered by preference, from which the client could select.  This would allow the client to react sensibly to failure of one endpoint by retrying using another.  The client could refresh the list at intervals (possibly guided by a TTL field in the list).